# Dynamic cast error in swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

Currently I am trying to loop through `NSArray` which contains `NSManagedObject`.
When I am trying to cast the fetched object its throwing me an error.
Here is the code

```
for var i = 0; i < self.displayedHistoryListContent.count ; i=i+1{
            var productObject: Product = self.displayedHistoryListContent.objectAtIndex(i) as Product
        }
```

Product is my `NSManagedObject`.

Application crashes at the line where I am doing casting 'as Product'

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Which kind of error have you?

Comment: -1: This is your 12th question, you should know how to format your question. The code is very hard to read this way. And you haven't posted the error message. If you put any effort into your question, why should we answer it?

Comment: libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x409678:  push   {r4, r7, lr}
0x40967a:  mov    r4, r0
0x40967c:  mov    r2, r1
0x40967e:  add    r7, sp, #0x4
0x409680:  cmp    r4, #0x0
0x409682:  beq    0x40969e                  ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 38
0x409684:  movw   r0, #0x8b8c
0x409688:  movt   r0, #0x1
0x40968c:  add    r0, pc
0x40968e:  ldr    r1, [r0]
0x409690:  mov    r0, r4objc_msgSend
0x409696:  tst.w  r0, #0xff
0x40969a:  bne    0x4096a0                  ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 40

Answer (score 1):

It really looks like your array does not contain `Product`s only. Try with `as?` instead of `as` to confirm this. You can use `NSLog` to see what is in the array when you expect a `Product`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the objects in the array are in fact of the class Product? When dealing with NSManagedObject's it is easy to get confused and refer to a set instead of the object itself.
You probably know that a cast is not a conversion?

Use a println() to see wat kind of object is really in there

Comment: Hi Rien, Yes it does contain Product NSManagedObject since its displaying correctly in my table view reloadData.

Comment: Not to belabour the point, but the runtime disagrees with you, have you tried the println(object)?